# Facebook Like Box / -Button: React to click

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-likebox

I'm creating a facebook app that should show content only to fans of a certain page. I can easily get the info whether the user is a fan of the page or not using FQL and want to display a *Like Box* or a *Like Button* if the user is not already a fan. After the user clicked onto *Like*, I'd like to display the content that is visible for fans only.

So here's my question: **Is it possible to react when the user clicks "*Like*"**? I've tried onclick, but it didn't work.

Here's the code of my Like Box:

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/myFanPage" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="false" data-header="false" data-stream="false" data-show-border="false" onclick="alert('TEST');"></div>
```

And the one for the Like Button:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/myFanPage" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false" onclick="alert('TEST2');"></div>
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, possible using `FB.Event.subscribe()` and **XFBML**

HTML:

```
<fb:like href="{Herf}" width="450"></fb:like>
```

JS:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: '{appID}',
        status: true,
        xfbml: true
    });

    // FB event listener 
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (url) {
     console.log('You liked the URL: ' + url);
    });
};
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AdamAzad/65wfx/)